# how to query display all data when not all related

Tags: mysql

I want to ask ..

If i have data but data related in another table

but i want the output is display all data

---

usually if data related in another table, I using INNER JOIN but the output just data have a relation, if dont have relation, its not display .. IF I using LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN not all data displayed .. IF I using UNION data duplicated

---

this just example field .. field in real so many

```
TABLE A

ID    |     NAMA     |   
----------------------
1     |     Rina     |   
2     |     Deni     |
3     |     Muti     |
4     |     Sina     |
5     |     Sasa     |


TABLE B
ID    |     Rumah    | 
----------------------  
1     |     Jabar    |   
2     |     Jateng   |
3     |     Jatim    |


OUTPUT THAT I WANT

ID    |     NAMA     |   Rumah 
---------------------------------- 
1     |     Rina     |   Jabar
2     |     Deni     |   Jateng
3     |     Muti     |   Jatim
4     |     Sina     |   -
5     |     Sasa     |   -
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, then a given ID might only have a first or last name, but not both.  In this case, simply doing a left or right join will result in the loss of data.  One approach here is to do a full outer join between your two tables on the ID, and then use `COALESCE` to handle possibly missing data appropriately.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID) AS ID,
       COALESCE(t1.NAMA, '-') AS NAMA,
       COALESCE(t2.Rumah, '-') AS Rumah
FROM TableA t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
UNION
SELECT COALESCE(t1.ID, t2.ID),
       COALESCE(t1.NAMA, '-')
       COALESCE(t2.Rumah, '-')
FROM TableA t1
RIGHT JOIN TableB t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

Comment: if using left join and field so many .. not field all displayed.. have another suggestion

Comment: @TARA I think the best you could do would be an outer join here.  This would allow all IDs to appear in the result set, even if an ID only has a first or last name, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

short version:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.ID, t2.ID),
       COALESCE(a.NAMA, '-')
       COALESCE(b.Rumah, '-')
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b
    ON a.ID = b.ID
RIGHT JOIN TableB t2
    ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Comment: Hi Ann, this might not work because the first `LEFT JOIN` could discard records in `TableB` which would then not be able to be included in the next `RIGHT JOIN`.